# how to show individual reports when login a user in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables(`users`,`client_reports`)common id for both tables  is `id_user`

- user tables columns are `id_user,name,email,password,phone`
- client_reports columns are `report_id,user_id,report,status`

from admin panel admin will add reports,before adding reports admin will select user and upload report.now i want to display user reports after login to his dashboard for his reports only.
     note:one user can have multiple reports.now i want to display reports in next1.php page.if user have 1 report that i have to display..if other user have two reports i have display 2 reports in next1.php

note:one user can have multiple reports.now i want to display reports in next1.php page.if user have 1 report that i have to display..if other user have two reports i have display 2 reports in next1.php

```
 <?php session_start(); 

 ini_set("display_errors",1);
 $host="localhost"; // database server name
$dbname="research";   // database name
$dbuser="root";   // database user name
$dbpassword=""; // database password



$conn=mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

 @$email=$_POST['email'];  
 @$password=$_POST['password'];  
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

 echo $sql="select * from users where email='".$email."' and password=".$password."";       
 $res=mysql_query($sql);  
 $nums=mysql_num_rows($res);  
 if($nums==1)  
 {  
      $result=mysql_fetch_array($res);  
      $_SESSION['email']=$result['email'];  
      $_SESSION['name']=$result['name'];  
      $_SESSION['id_user']=$result['id_user'];  
      ?>
      <script>location.href='next1.php';</script>;
 <?php      
 }  
 else  
 {  
 echo "<script>alert('invalid details')</script>";       
 }  
 }  
 ?>  
 <style>  
 table {  
      background:#8FC283;  
      margin-top:150px;  
      border-radius:5px;  
 }  
 </style>  
 <form method="post">  
 <table align="center" border="0">  
 <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td></tr>  
 <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td></tr>  
 <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>  
 </table>   
 </form>  
 <h2>New to this website<a href='register.php'>signup</a></h2>

next1.php:
<?php session_start();  
   echo "Welcome&nbsp;".@$_SESSION['email'];  
 ?>  
 <ul>  

 <ol><a href="logout11.php">Logout</a></ol>  
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In next1.php, use your session variable

```
$currentLoggedInUser = $_SESSION['id_user'];
```

Now use current logged in user's id to display

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM client_reports WHERE id_user = '$currentLoggedInUser' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["user_id"]. " - " . $row["status"]. " " . $row["report_id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```